# Pings disabled but Wordpress is still searching for "to_ping"

Tags: wp-cron

I have a client's site that has over 200k posts in it and I am trying to optimize it as best I can. Currently under the Settings -> Discussion page both "Attempt to notify any blogs linked to from the article" and "Allow link notifications from other blogs (pingbacks and trackbacks) on new articles" are unchecked, yet I am still seeing this in the slow query logs (being called from wp-cron.php):

```
# Query_time: 43.475373  Lock_time: 0.000056  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 227718  Rows_affected: 0
# Bytes_sent: 81
SET timestamp=1494303060;
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE to_ping <> '' AND post_status = 'publish'
```

Is there any way I can globally unset this? Is there is a hook somewhere that I can override in the theme?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently what I was looking for was a hook that sets "do_ping", and grepping through the theme and plugins there was none. My guess is that it was set through either an old theme or plugin, and not unset when that was deleted. However, I did discover that this function will globally unset it regardless of where it came from, and prevent it from being re-set:

```
if (isset($_GET['doing_wp_cron'])) {
    remove_action('do_pings', 'do_all_pings');
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('do_pings');
}
```

Thanks to this site for the solution:

https://wp-mix.com/wordpress-clean-up-do_pings/